# Entries keep on getting doubled when entered on PHP MY Admin

Tags: php, html, database, phpmyadmin

I'm using PHPMyAdmin as part of a tutorial but find that whenever data is is entered into the database, the record for that particular entry is doubled, meaning that I effectively get two times the the data for the same entry.
Is there just a problem with a setting?

Comment: You probably run the query twice. But without seeing how your code looks, its impossible for us to be more specific.

Comment: Are you using the `phpMyAdmin` application or your own code with a `mysql` database (a common point of confusion)? If you're using `phpMyAdmin` without any of your own code, then I've only ever seen this happen when a user double-clicks buttons.